# Postgres regexp_replace, remove "st", "nd", "rd"

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

I need remove above suffixes and keep just a number and other text.

The string for example:

```
Start from 1st, 2nd, 3rd
```

Should be

```
Start from 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an or condition on the three possible values:

```
select regexp_replace(the_column, '(st)|(nd)|(rd)', '', 'g') as new_value
from the_table;
```

You might also want to use case **in**sensitive replacing, by using the flags `'gi'` instead of just `'g'`.

If those string can appear for themselves (i.e. not following a number) you need to extend the regex:

```
regexp_replace(the_column, '([0-9])((st)|(nd)|(rd))', '\1', 'g')
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/6533

Comment: It is not suitable as it removes all characters 'st', 'nd' etc which as well is not belong to numbers

Comment: @user3627553: did you see my second regex? Btw: you should include things like that in your initial question, not come up with additional information once you have an answer

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!
The second is fully that I need

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

`regexp_replace(source, pattern, replacement [, flags ])`

So for your case this should do the trick:

`regexp_replace(YOUR_SOURCE, '(\d*+(\w{2}))', '', 'g')`

Comment: That will replace the numbers as well

Comment: Corrected (see above) - will also match 5**th** etc

Comment: Still doesn't work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/6530 (and `\d*+` gives an error as well)

Answer (score 0):

Matches 5**th** and 11**th** as well

`regexp_replace(the_column, '([\d+])(\w{2})', '\1', 'g')`